# How to manage layers interleaved using z-index

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, styles, z-index

I have some difficulties to manage multiple interleaved layers.

[I reproduced my issue in this Plunker example](https://plnkr.co/edit/Lt0CWgPaUfecU93nSZR4?p=preview)

```
  <body>
<header>
  <nav class="navbar">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="http://example.com" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            Dropdown link
          </a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
<nav class="navbar row filter">
  <form class="form-inline">
    <input name="search" class="form-control" type="text" size="30"/>
  </form>
</nav>
```

```
header {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: top center;
  background-size: 100%;
  position: relative;
  height: 80px;
  z-index: 100;
}

header .navbar {
  padding:0;
}

.dropdown-menu {
  z-index:300;
}

.filter {
  margin-top:-20px;
  background-color: black;
}

.filter form {
 z-index:200;
}
```

If I start from the farthest element, I should have :

1. the filter bar container
2. the header container
3. the filter bar content (input)
4. the header content (menu)

So I specified:

- **the header** with a z-index 100 to go hover the filter bar
- **the filter bar content** with a z-index 200 to go hover the header
- **the dropdown menu** with a z-index 300 to go over all components...this one is not working, it stays under the filter bar content....why ?

I am not an expert in css, maybe there is a better ways to achieve this design but I don't understand why the dropdown menu is not over all component ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple :) You just need to adjust z-index between header & navbar.

```
header {
  z-index: 301;
}

navbar{
  z-index: 300;
}
```

Have fun

Edit: After understanding what you want exactly, [you can take a look at this](https://plnkr.co/edit/Ri1E3VqKQPd6RGNDqNJS?p=preview)

Comment: In this case, the top of the input in not focusable....because the transparent image of the header is over it....

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove z-index from header and add z-index to navbar as below

```
header {
  background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,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);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: top center;
  background-size: 100%;
  position: relative;
  height: 80px;
}

navbar{
   z-index: 100;
}
```

Comment: As you could see in the plunker example, the header should be over the filter bar. The header contains a background image with a white rectangle that has to be over the filter bar. It is why I put a z-index on the header